# Remove specific string from file's name using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need your help.

I've multiple `.txt files` with following nomenclature:

`test-test-test-201602291545.txt`

`test-test-test-test-test-201602291540.txt`

I want to remove "test" sub string from file name and final result should be like:

`201602291545.txt`,

`201602291540.txt`

Please do let me know how I can do this using simple batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that you need some way to split off all of the `test-` strings from the beginning of the file name. The code below uses a `FOR` loop with `"delims=-"` to do that.

The repetitive lines could probably be improved. `dbenham` could (should) chime in here. I did some search, but did not find anything.

WARNING: UNTESTED CODE

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "RESULT="

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`DIR /B /A:-D "test-*.txt"`) DO (
    SET "RESULT="

    FOR /F "tokens=1-30 delims=-" %%b IN ("%%~a") DO (
        IF /I "%%b" NEQ "" IF /I "%%b" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%b")
        IF /I "%%c" NEQ "" IF /I "%%c" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%c")
        IF /I "%%d" NEQ "" IF /I "%%d" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%d")
        IF /I "%%e" NEQ "" IF /I "%%e" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%e")
        IF /I "%%f" NEQ "" IF /I "%%f" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%f")
        IF /I "%%g" NEQ "" IF /I "%%g" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%g")
        IF /I "%%h" NEQ "" IF /I "%%h" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%h")
        IF /I "%%i" NEQ "" IF /I "%%i" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%i")
        IF /I "%%j" NEQ "" IF /I "%%j" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%j")
        IF /I "%%k" NEQ "" IF /I "%%k" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%k")
        IF /I "%%l" NEQ "" IF /I "%%l" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%l")
        IF /I "%%m" NEQ "" IF /I "%%m" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%m")
        IF /I "%%n" NEQ "" IF /I "%%n" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%n")
        IF /I "%%o" NEQ "" IF /I "%%o" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%o")
        IF /I "%%p" NEQ "" IF /I "%%p" NEQ "test" (SET "RESULT=%%p")
    )

    IF "!RESULT!" NEQ "" (
        ECHO RENAME "%%~a" !RESULT!
    )
)
```

If "test-" cannot appear after the desired filename begins the a better way of probably something like the following. Note that the duplicate name detection will not be made until the `ECHO` is removed from the `RENAME` command.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`DIR /B /A:-D "test-*.txt"`) DO (
    SET "V=%%a"
    SET "RESULT=!V:test-=!

    IF "!RESULT!" NEQ "" (
        IF EXIST "!RESULT!" (
            ECHO ERROR: Cannot rename %%a because !RESULT! already exists.
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO RENAME "%%~a" !RESULT!
        )
    )
)
```